# VLC, SMPlayer doesn't show other partitions

Tags: vlc, ntfs, smplayer

So I was trying to install VLC through the command line, as I did with other distros. After installation I found that I can only access my linux partition/s, but not the other partitions/drives(when I choose to **open a directory** my other partitions aren't even there!). The same problem is with SMPlyaer.

A little digging showed me that I've might've installed the snap version, but that isn't the case either.

I tried installing from the software center, but to no avail...

There's a snap version on the software center, and another version that's not obviously a snap version. I tried both of them...

I installed and used Ubuntu a long time ago, it was my intro into Linux, ans I was perfectly able to install and play with VLC without any problem. I didn't have this type of problem on Mint or Manjaro either...

So what's going on here?

Here' what I have when I try to open a file on SMPlayer, it's the same case when I'm using VLC:

["Choose a file tab on SMPlayer"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8NIO.png)

As you can see I only have my root partition there for selection, not any other partitions(Windows NTFS partitions...)

Comment: it's probable that the other partitions you hoped to see were not yet mounted.

Comment: are the other partitions mounted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the screenshot, only your root partition is shown. This is normal, as a lot of the applications present this exact screen when asked to select files as well.

Now, this might solve your problem:

1. Make sure you have the partitions mounted through `Nautilus` or other applications you would like to use.
2. Enter the folder `/media/sakib`. In there it should show the list of partition you mounted.

In the following screenshot you can see that my partitions are mounted in `/run/media/cynplytholowazy/`, and once you enter the folder you will see the list of partitions you have mounted. (It's probably in your `/media/sakib` folder)

[image: Folder list view]

Comment: That worked!!

My question sounds so trivial and stupid now! I should've tried what you just said- on Manjaro KDE this same thing happed, but there I had my partitions listed on the left, but when I mounted them from VLC, they showed up in /media/sakib; that just didn't click in my head here in this case!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, many people just didn't realize that it can be done through checking `/media/(user)` as well.